# Passing viewModel StateObject into other view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, view, binding

I have created a login screen and to simplify the overall code, I created a struct for LoginView and one for SignUp. This working fine, but I need to pass a viewModel reference from the main View. I cannot find a way to do it.

Below is the code:

```
struct LoginView: View {
        
    @State var index = 0
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = LoginViewModelImpl(service: LoginServiceImpl())
    
    @State var forgotEmail = ""

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Image("logo_name")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 200.0)
                    .padding(.top, 80)
                
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack {
                    Signup(index: self.$index)
                        .zIndex(Double(self.index))
```

As you can see, I can already pass `index` in the `Signup` call but I cannot find a way to pass the `@StateObject viewModel`

The `Signup` is as below:

```
struct Signup : View {
    
    ---> Binding to pass viewmodel
    
    @Binding var index : Int
    
    var body: some View {
       ....
            
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.register()
            }) {
                Text("Signup")
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `@Binding` is got value types not reference types

Comment: The View structs are the view model already and pass data down as let or binding. So you can just remove the view model objects and your problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

A `StateObject` can simply be passed by reference, like any class. If the receiving view needs to observe changes to the model then it needs to be defined with `var`and have the attribute `@ObservedObject`.

From the `body` of the owning view (`LoginView`):

```swift
    Signup(viewModel: viewModel, index: self.$index)
```

In the receiving view (`Signup`)

```swift
struct Signup : View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: LoginViewModelImpl
    @Binding var index : Int
```

If the receiving view does not actually need to observe changes to the model then you don't need the `@ObservedObject` attribute and it can be defined with `let` instead.